# Need a Regex that adds a space after a period, but can account for abbreviations such as U.S. or D.C

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Here is what I have so far:

```
text = re.sub((?<=\.)(?=[A-Z]), text)
```

This already avoids numbers and it gets around non-capital letters, but I need it to account for the edge case where initials are separated by periods.

An example sentence where I wouldn't want to add a space would be:

```
The U.S. health care is more expensive than U.K health care.
```

Currently, my regex makes it like:

```
The U. S. health care is more expensive than U. K health care.
```

But I want it to look exactly like the first sentence without the spaces separating U.S and U.K

I'm not sure how to do this, any advice would be appreciated!

EDIT:

```
(?<=\.)(?=[A-Z][a-z]{1,})
```

makes it so that it avoids one word abbreviations.

Comment: Maybe `r'(?<=\.)(?=[A-Z]\B)'`? See https://regex101.com/r/4JG0qL/1

Comment: `{1,}` is just a really hard way to type `+`

Comment: Could you modify your example to show where spaces are added as well as where they are not?

Comment: What if there is `test.A!` ? Perhaps like this `(?<=\.)(?=[A-Z][^\sA-Z\.])` https://regex101.com/r/C867EM/1

Comment: What is the difference between `P.Hd` as an abbreviation and `end of sentence with I.And start of another one` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this does what you want. We find points which do not have a capital letter before them, nor a space after.

```regex
import re
text="The U.S. health care is more expensive than U.K health care.The end."
text = re.sub(r'((?<![A-Z])\.(?!\s))',r'\1 ', text)
print('<',text,'>')
```

output (with '<' and '>' to show the beginning and end of the text more clearly.

```
< The U.S. health care is more expensive than U.K health care. The end.  >
```